# why i got this error: No such file or directory Error during processing

Tags: python

```
folder_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Alkesh Patil\velocity 16apr notes\06_13_OCR_PDF2IMAGE\pcard"
path = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract"
image_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path

pan_num = []
dob_num = []

for image in image_list:
    images = os.path.join(folder_path, image)
    print(image)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    print(text)
```

Comment: Please show the actual error and traceback you're getting.

Comment: POST the complete stacktrace